# Parameters through postback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with Ruby on rails 2.3.4 and I'd like to pass some parameters from one page to another ones the first one is submitted.

For example:

On the first page, I have a form that when it's filled a Preview button can be clicked to check all the info entered before submitting the form. That button redirects to another page with the info entered before, but I don't know how to get it in the second page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1. You can emulate the stepped form filling by creating a record in first form and saving it with status "unverified" or "pending". This way you won't have to deal with hidden form fields in 2nd and 3rd pages. All you'll need to pass is the id of pending record. You'll just need to update record status to "active" once the data is confirmed.
2. Use client side paginated from (all popular JS frameworks have plugins for this). Hence you will only display different `<div>`s in single loaded page (something like an interface for a setup wizard).

Comment: Yes I thought about the first one, but honestly I didn't see that as the best solution. Let's see if more solutions are posted, if not I'll accept yours. Thank you.